# How to change theme in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I would like to change the theme/color of odoo. I am looking for a way to change the theme globaly, not just the website that seems to be detailed in this page https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/website_themes/theming.html#

When I go to the main odoo page, I can see different apps. When I click into one of the apps, there is where I want to change the theme, e.g. navigation bar color, etc. Is this possible?

I am new to odoo. So I might misuse the term here. If so, please feel free to correct me, and send me some links! Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

By default it isn't possible to change the back-end theme colors. You have to download an app from the Odoo App Store to do that. I have used [this one from MukIT](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/themes/16.0/muk_web_theme/) before. It's free and it works well.